# If/Else jQuery is breaking my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set-up an if/else statement that if a class exists then the `var num` will equal 100, if the class does not exist then `var num` will equal 55. `num` is then used to understand how many pixels the screen will be offset. Any help will be appreciated as Javascript is one of my weak points.

```
// Add scrollspy to <body>
$('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 55});

// Checks to see if navbar is affixed or not
if (($(".affix-top")[0]){) {
  num = 100;
} else {
  num = 55;
}

// Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
$(".navbar-lower a").on('click', function(event) {

  // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
  if (this.hash !== "") {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (300) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - num
    }, 300, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });

  } // End if

});
```

Comment: Did you check your console? ...`if (($(".affix-top")[0]){) {`

Comment: @mhodges when I paste that into my console, it returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: That's what they're telling you. Your code (which they copied exactly) has a syntax error

Comment: you have a extra { within "if (($(".affix-top")[0]){)" this section change it to if "(($(".affix-top")[0]))"

Comment: You said Jquery, why not just target the nav and use .hasClass('affix-top').
Targeting an object that might not be there doesn't seem like a very good style.

Comment: @AndrewIce the reason behind it is that `.affix-top` is only a class that appears on the page if you're above a certain height. I am doing this because we are using anchor links and because of the fixed navbar on top, it covers some of the content. My fix was to minus -55 pixels from anchor drop point, which only fixed it if you weren't at the top of the page.

Comment: Yeah, no I figured from the offset matching the values you were passing that it was probably a "responsive" navbar.  The affix might not always be on the page, but is not the element it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to read.

```
 if (($(".affix-top")[0]){) {
     num = 100;
 } else {
    num = 55;
 }
```

It can be simplified to just this, because anything matched is *true*.

```
 var num = $(".affix-top").length ? 100 : 55;
```

That will not work if the script runs before the rest of the HTML page has loaded.

```
 <script type="application/javascript"> $(".affix-top").length > 0; // false </script>
 <div class="affix-top"></div>
 <script type="application/javascript"> $(".affix-top").length > 0; // true </script>
```

So wrap everything in a jQuery ready block.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       var num = $(".affix-top").length ? 100 : 55;
       //....... insert more code here
  });
```

Comment: I tried to use this, however it still prints out the second number every time, even if the class doesn't exist.

Comment: @Cody Affix has events you can listen for. That might provide better functionality then matching the CSS class. Take a let at: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-affix.php

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the extra brackets. Also, just check `.length` to see if an element exists. It's subjective but IMO it makes it easier to read.

```
if ( $(".affix-top").length ) {
    num = 100;
} else {
    num = 55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a { where it doesn't belong

```
if (($(".affix-top")[0]){) {
```

should be

```
if (($(".affix-top")[0])) {
```